# Shinydashboard landing page

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

When using runApp() with shinyDashboard, the app loading with the first tab as default. Any way to change the first page for something like 'welcome' instead of directly loading the first tab?

Comment: there is plenty of info on SO or on google. You should provide a reproducible example so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `updateTabItems` command in your server.R

If you want it to fire when the application starts you'll want to put it inside an `observe`

```
observe({
  updateTabItems(session, "menuTabId", 'tabIdToChangeTo')
})
```

If you want this functionality to repeat depending on some value, you'll want to add a reactive input or reactive value inside the observe scope to trigger the `observe` once that value changes.